# How to convert decimal to 64bit binary and load it to a bitarray (not byte array)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Please provide me the code to convert `15698` which is stored in a `Int64` and load the binary bits to a `bitarray`

please see the image here [chart](http://i.share.pho.to/42e21abf_o.jpeg)

Comment: I have no idea how to do it that's why I asked, atleast tell me if there's a vb function to get it converted ..

Comment: Use `Convert.ToString(15698, 2).PadLeft(64, '0')`

Comment: Read the documentation of the [BitArray constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3d1dwck(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN. There is no version that creates a `BitArray` from an `Int64`, but there is one that creates one from an array of `Int32`. All you need to do is create an array of two `Int32` and store the high order bits in one element and the low order bits in the other.

Comment: Be carefull with your title, [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx) is not the same as [Int64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int64(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Since the `BitArray` constructor does not take an `Int64` argument, you need to first convert it to a byte array.  You can use the `BitConverter` class to do that:

```
Dim input As Long = 15698
Dim b As New BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(input))
```

Obviously, when converting to byte and bit arrays, you may need to concern yourself with endianness.

Comment: Nice use of endianness

Comment: I searched google for endianness ... since most of the computers use little-endian as I see, will it be a problem?

Comment: I don't know if it would be a problem because I don't know for what you are doing it.  Usually you only care about endianness if you are writing to a standard file format which dictates proper byte-order, or if you are sending the data to another computer.

Comment: I'll save those data to a file using `File.WriteAllBytes` to the hard-disk

Comment: It all depends what byte order you expect/want them to be in.  As long as you expect them to be in little-endian order, and you only ever run your application on a little-endian machine, then, yes, you'll be fine.

Comment: is there a method to bypass this endian scenario ? just like a check to see if the machine uses little or big then changing the loading to bitarray order

Comment: The `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` lets you know the endianness of the current machine.

Answer (score -2):

Some different way.

```
Dim valueToConvert As Int64 = 15698
Dim bitArray = New Boolean(63) {}
For i As var = 0 To bitArray.Length - 1
    bitArray(i) = (tempVal Mod 2) = 1
    valueToConvert =  valueToConvert >> 1
Next
Dim result as New BitArray(bitArray);
```

Comment: Yes, there was small mistake. Bitwise shift operators are not only c++ operators. From my perspective it's more clear then fighting with bytes and -endian.

Comment: You'd still need to be careful of the endianness, even in your example.  Also, your method is significantly less efficient since it's having to perform a division operation to calculate each bit.  Even with using a bit-shifting algorithm, it would be better to use a bit-wise *and* operation to calculate each bit.

Comment: You seem to be missing something. You are using the value in `tempVal` to set the bits in the array, but nowhere do you set or change the value of `tempVal`.